# Jest: Cannot set property ' ' of undefined (Angular)

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jestjs

I started to write unit tests and have some issue.
Test failed with error
`TypeError: Cannot set property 'birthday' of undefined`

Maybe someone can give an advise how to make it work correctly.
Would be really grateful for any help!

My code:

CandidateItemComponent.ts

```
export class CandidateItemComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() candidate: Candidate;
  @Input() isAdmin: boolean;
  birthday: string;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.birthday = this.candidate.birthday;
  }
}
```

CandidateItemComponent.html

```
<div *ngFor="let property of visibleCandidateProperties"
     class="candidate-item"
     [attr.title]="property.propertyKey === 'age' ? birthday : ''">
  {{candidate[property.propertyKey]}}
</div>
```

CandidateItemComponent.spec.ts

```
import { async, ComponentFixture, fakeAsync, TestBed, tick } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { CandidateItemComponent } from './candidate-item.component';

describe('CandidateItemComponent', () => {
  let component: CandidateItemComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<CandidateItemComponent>;
  const mockIsAdmin = true;
  const mockBirthday = '12-07-1997';

  const mockCandidate = {
    id: 2,
    firstName: 'Alexander',
    lastName: 'Osichanskiy',
    email: 'sashaoles1727@gmail.com',
    phone: '380638732626',
    birthday: '12-07-1997',
  };

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [CandidateItemComponent],
    }).compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(CandidateItemComponent);
    component = fixture.debugElement.componentInstance;
    component.isAdmin = mockIsAdmin;
    component.birthday = mockBirthday;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

that's because you also need to set the **candidate** input along with other inputs,

```
it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
    component.isAdmin = mockIsAdmin;
    component.birthday = mockBirthday;

    component.candidate = mockCandidate;         // here

    fixture.detectChanges();
  });
```

Comment: Thanks for this. The error message literally could not be any worse.